# Trying to add a parameter to my sqldatasource during rowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

So I have a gridview within a gridview (I have a one to many table) my first gridview is working well, but my second gridview has a sqldatasource that has a select parameter(the default value was just for testing)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCountryByTripID" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bahDatabase %>" 
        SelectCommand="spSelectCitiesByTripID" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="tripID"  DefaultValue="56" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

during my Gridview1 row databound I am trying to grab the columns that match the tripID. But dsCountryByTripID which is my datasource, is only going inputted with the last tripID.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv2 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView2");
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            dsCountryByTripID.SelectParameters.Clear();
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            string tripID = (drv["pkiTripId"]).ToString();
            dsCountryByTripID.SelectParameters.Add("tripID", DbType.Int32, tripID);
            //gv2.DataBind();
            //e.Row.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can read why it only executes the last "tripId": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw738475(VS.80).aspx
The sql datasource only gets executed at the end of the page, so every time you go through a row the tripID is overriden.

Do you really need to use the datasource? Can't you use ado.net or something different for you dataaccess?

Hope this helps.

Comment: so you are saying because the sql datasource is executed at the end, I should code ado.net manually so I can call it whenever I want? this might work..

Comment: @spooks, that's exactly what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to clarify the structure of your page. It seems to me that `dsCountryByTripID` is declared outside of Gridview1, instead of inside Gridview1. That's probably why your `dsCountryByTripID` is only going inputted with the last tripID.

In order to do what you want, the structure should be like this:

```
<asp:gridview id="gv1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds1">
...
    <asp:gridview id="gv2nested" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsCountryByTripID">
    </asp:gridview>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCountryByTripID" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bahDatabase %>" 
    SelectCommand="spSelectCitiesByTripID" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="tripID"  DefaultValue="56" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
...
</asp:gridview>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds1" runat="server" >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Next, to assign the correct value to the inner datasource selectparameter, you can do that in the outer gridview (`gv1`) RowCreated event handler.

```
protected void gv1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve the inner gridview
        //Retrieve the inner sqldatasource
        //Retrieve and assign selectparameter value
    }
```

It's similar to the C# code you posted, but you need to additionally use FindControl to retrieve the now **nested** sqldatasource (dsCountryByTripID) before assigning the value to the selectparameter. (Trying to teach a man fishing here, but let me know if you need more help or if the above is not your case :)